# How to list the grants for a certain table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to list the grants that have been given to users for a certain table?

I do **not** want to go through all users and ask for all the grants they have been given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These informations are stored in the `Information_schema` database, in a table named `TABLE_PRIVILEGES`.

Run a SQL like this :

```
USE INFORMATION_SCHEMA;
SELECT * FROM `TABLE_PRIVILEGES` WHERE TABLE_NAME="myTable";
```

Or navigate into that table using `phpmyadmin`.

**Edit :**

You can find Schema/Database permissions infos in table `SCHEMA_PRIVILEGES` in database `information_schema`

```
USE INFORMATION_SCHEMA;
SELECT * FROM `SCHEMA_PRIVILEGES` WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA="myDatabase";
```

Comment: Great ! so please mark as answered ;)

Comment: just found the absolutely unintuitive way to do so - click on a symbol with no letter saying what is does.

Comment: Just one caveat, that only lists the explicit table privileges and does not include users that have implicit access to that table because of broader priviliges e.g. on the whole schema/database (as a result of `GRANT some_priv ON schema.* TO ...`) nor the root or other users that have permissions on all schema's. ( the result of `GRANT some_priv ON *.* TO ...`)

Comment: Yes but that is not what you were asking for in your initial question ;) I've updated my answer